# ASP.net Routing Problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using asp.net Routing technique to map physical file("~/Financial/GL/AccountCategory.aspx") to a user friendly URL ("Home/Application/General_Ledger/Definitions/Account_Category"):

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("Route1", 
    "Home/Application/General_Ledger/Definitions/Account_Category",
    "~/Financial/GL/AccountCategory.aspx");
```

but when the user presses the link which has its URL referencing the user friendly URL I got exception with message:

> "Cannot use a leading `..` to exit above the top directory"

I know that the exception raised because the directory structure level of the friendly URL is greater than the one of the physical file, but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Can you tell me in which way are you calling the redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't have enough information to answer it.

- What URL are they on when they press the link?
- What's the URL of the link itself (view source please)?
- How did you generate the link?

My guess is that whatever you are using to generate the link is not taking into consideration the new route. So the link is generating some relative path "../../" which corresponds to the physical location, but it should be corresponding to the route.